# How to download all photos that I uploaded to Facebook into my computer?

Tags: facebook, osx

I need to delete my Facebook account, but before I do that, I need to clean it up first from all of my information. How do I **download all photos** that I uploaded to Facebook into my computer? Opening them one by one manually and then right click to save it as a photo in my local computer is definitely a hassle.

Is there an easy way to do this?

I use Mac OS X 10.5.8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Login to your Facebook account then go to **Account >> Account Settings**. Look for **Download Your Information** in the Settings tabs then click on “**learn more**” in the right side. Click on “**Download**‘ button. It shows a warning messages they click **Okey** to continue. You will receive a email from Facebook once it is ready for download with the download information. Just follow the steps mentioned in the email and you are done!

Comment: Thanks for your detail step by step explanation, it's working.

Answer (score 3):

From the *Facebook [Help Center](https://www.facebook.com/help/?faq=212802592074644)* :

> **How can I download my information from Facebook?**
>   You can download your information from the Account Settings page.
>   Open the Account dropdown menu at the top right corner of Facebook and choose Account Settings.
>   At the bottom of your general account settings, click Download a copy of your Facebook data.
>   Click the Download button on the following page.

It includes photos and videos.

Answer (score 0):

I would personally use the iphone app PhotoJacker. [You can download it here](http://download.photojacker.com).

It's extremely easy, it syncs to your facebook and you click on the albums you want to save. It is then all saved to your personal dropbox. I really recommend it. You can also save photos that you were tagged in.